# topic transmits messages of same type?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be a very basic doubt but has been bugging me for quite sometime. When messages are being transmitted on a topic , is it necessary that all these messages are of same message type ? else md5 sum has to be checked for every message that the publisher sends

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253728/topic-transmits-messages-of-same-type-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When messages are being transmitted on a topic , is it necessary that all these messages are of same message type

Yes. In fact, it's enforced.

---

Edit:

> will md5 sum remain same on a topic ?

yes.

> or does it change with each message although they are of same type?

The MD5 of a message is calculated as follows (from [wiki/ROS/Technical Overview - Message serialization and msg MD5 sums](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Message_serialization_and_msg_MD5_sums)):

> For reference, this MD5 sum is calculated from the *MD5 text* of the `.msg file`, where the *MD5 text* is the `.msg` text with:

> - comments removed

- whitespace removed
- package names of dependencies removed
- constants reordered ahead of other declarations

> In order to catch changes that occur in embedded message types, the MD5 text is concatenated with the MD5 text of each of the embedded types, in the order that they appear.

So, provided that the *type* never changes, and message *contents* or *values* are not considered: no, the MD5 sum never changes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-03**:
In such a case , will md5 sum remain same on a topic ? or does it change with each message although they are of same type?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:
Btw: I'm more than happy to keep answering your questions, and I admire your inquisitive nature, but seeing as you happen to be asking questions about parts of ROS that are actually rather well documented (not something we can universally claim), you might want to search the wiki a bit yourself.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-03**:
Pardon me.As the documentation is exhaustive,I keep getting lost in it looking for a particular answers. But I have checked with turtlesim simulator as an example and found that each .msg file could contain one or more msg types,however,md5 checksum remains unique for a msg type.Thank you very much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:\

> Pardon me.

No need. As I said, it's not a problem, but it might save you some time waiting for others to answer you.

> As the documentation is exhaustive

I must say that this is not something I hear many (beginning) users say about ROS ;)